# Contiguity and limiting distributions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $p_n \rightarrow p$ weakly or in measure/distribution and $q_n = q$ remains fixed in $n$. 
 Assume only that $p$ and $q$ are continuous probability distributions.  Intuitively, it would make sense that if $q(A_n) \rightarrow 0$ implies $p(A_n) \rightarrow 0$, then $q(A_n) \rightarrow 0$ implies $p_n(A_n) \rightarrow 0$ (i.e. we have contiguity), but is this the case?

Obviously $p_n((-\infty, x]) \rightarrow p_n((-\infty, x])$ so that $p_n(A) \rightarrow p(A)$ for all Borel sets $A$, but this is only true for fixed $A$ and is not necessarily true uniformly in $A_n$ arbitrary sets.  Can the uniform convergence for sets $A_n$ be implied?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Let $(X_i)$ be i.i.d. with $\mathbb P(X_i=1)=\mathbb P(X_i=-1)=\frac12$, and let $p_n$ be the law of $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. By the central limit theorem, we have that $p_n\to p$ weakly, where $p$ is the law of a $\mathcal N(0,1)$ random variable. Let $q=p$, so your condition is trivially satisfied, and let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure.

Observe that $p_n$ is supported on $\{\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}: -n \le k \le n\}$. Hence, defining
$$A_n:=\bigcup_{k=-n}^n\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}-2^{-n},\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}+2^{-n}\right),$$ one has $p_n(A_n)=1$ for all $n$. However, $\lambda(A_n)=2(n+1)2^{-n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, which implies $q(A_n)\to0$. Thus, this is a counterexample.